# uploading image file only _ Spring

Tags: spring, file-upload, image-uploading

I've been started one simple website project to study Spring. I'm trying to check file extension and upload only image file on the board. So I added if else statement before upload file but it dosen't seem working correctly.
My code is below:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {
@RequestMapping("/write")
public String write(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("bFile") MultipartFile bFile, Model model) {
    System.out.println("writeDao()");

    String savePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/fileUpload");

    String originalFName = bFile.getOriginalFilename();
    String onlyFName = originalFName.substring(0, originalFName.indexOf("."));
    String extension = originalFName.substring(originalFName.indexOf(".")); // .jpg
    String rename = onlyFName + "_" + getCurrentDayTime() + extension; // fileName_20150721-14-07-50.jpg
    String fullPath = savePath + "\\" + rename;

    if(!bFile.getContentType().equals("images/jpeg")) {
        try{
            byte[] bytes = bFile.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fullPath)));               
            stream.write(bytes);

            stream.close();

            System.out.println("Success to upload file");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fail to upload file");

        }

    } else {
           System.out.println("Choose file to upload");
    }

    String bPwd = request.getParameter("bPwd");
    BoardDao dao = sqlSession.getMapper(BoardDao.class);
    dao.writeDao(pwd, rename, fullPath);

    return "redirect:list";
}


//file upload.jsp
<form action="write" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
    <td> File </td>
    <td> <input type="file" multiple accept='image/*'  name="bFile" size = "50"> </td>
</tr>   
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem? Are you receiving an exception? If then can you specify? Where do you get the problem exactly, have you tried debugging ?

Comment: @Redfx I'm getting no errors, it just give me only "Success to upload file" even though I uploaded .txt file. If - else statement dosen't work correctly

Comment: Alright.. Can you debug and try to understand what the getContentType method is returning? Let's see what we've got

Comment: @Redfx This time I tried this code below: public static final String PNG_MIME_TYPE="image/jpeg";   if(PNG_MIME_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(bFile.getContentType())) {...} and I uploaded txt file. It still upload file to website but got different message, "System.out.println("Choose file to upload");"

Comment: @Redfx But how do I check before I upload the file?

Comment: @Redfx Oh I figured out how to check file type before upload file but why still png file can be uploaded even though I fixed the file type to images/jpg?

Comment: I saw it as "image/jpg" image being singular. Might that be the issue ? Can you try it ?